# Startup same .exe file with different app.config 's

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, prism, app-config

Is there a way (maybe from command line) to start the same exe file twice using a different app config?

Comment: you mean, other than put it in 2 different directories with 2 different .config files?

Comment: I just don't wont to copy all .exe files and .dll's to a second directory. therefore i just want to put 2 app.configs in the same directory and create 2 Start links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"myconfigpath";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start it from a separate location, where the filename.exe.config is different.

Answer (score 0):

THe configuration framework let you load the config from any file but you will have to handle that manually from within your application.

Look at `ConfigurationManager` class

Answer (score 0):

You can load your process into a separate app domain. This allows you to redirect the configuration file. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/HostingMultipleServices.aspx for an example of doing this with a Windows service. It'll be similar for any kind of application.